# Homology and Homotopy group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

$E, F, B$ are topological space, $B$ path connected. If we have given a long exact sequence..
$$\cdots\to \pi_1(F)\to \pi_1(E)\to \pi_1(B)\to\cdots$$

what will the relationship of $H_1(F,\mathbb R)$, $H_1(E,\mathbb R)$ and $H_1(B,\mathbb R)$

Comment: First of all, what of kind of arrow do you have? Embeddings? Second of all. Secondly to define $\pi_1(X)$ X has to be locally path-connected and connected. Moreover, to define $H_1(X,\mathbb R)$ you need more in general: a simplicial structure, or manifold, etc. You must be more precise, specially with arrows.

Comment: Why should we need any more structure than topological on $X$ to define, say, the singular homology?

Also, this looks like a long exact sequence to me. Should there be zeroes on the ends?

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre_spectral_sequence? Your notation suggests (assuming you mean "long exact sequence" rather than "short exact sequence") that $F \to E \to B$ is a fiber sequence, in which case the Serre spectral sequence lets you describe the homology of $E$ in terms of that of $F$ and $B$.

Comment: Why should we need any more structure than topological on $X$ to define $\pi_1(X)$?